# eBay - is it possible to list internationally only and not domestically?

Tags: ebay

I have an item I want to list on eBay.

I only want to list this specific item internationally, I don't want it to show up on domestic listings. Is that possible?

This is only for a handful of listing, for my other listings I just list them as both domestic and international.

Answer (score 0):

You can only be registered in the country you are in, and you deal with the tax implications of that country (and MP, bank account, and all that). You can log into any eBay site (most of them anyway) and LIST your item. As long as you provide shipping to the country you are listing in, you are good to go.

I'm in Canada and everything I do is on the US site, including the location of my store. For MP registration they required a bank account in Canada.